# Adding a variable copying the one before and the one after for a long list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 different lists that I would like to modify:
The first one goes like so :

```
['chelsea','manchester','london','liverpool',..]
```

The list is quite long and goes on for a while.
I would like to get it like so :

```
['chelsea','chelsea-manchester','manchester','london','london-liverpool','liverpool',...]
```

and so on.

The second one is one with lots of numbers in

```
 ['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21'..]
```

which also goes on for a long time.
I want to modify the list to get rid of the 4th and 5th variables for each block of 5 variables like so :

```
['10','11','12','15','16','17','20','21','22']
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```py
data = ['chelsea','manchester','london','liverpool']
data_connect = [[data[0]]] + [[f"{data[i-1]}-{data[i]}", data[i]] for i, x in enumerate(data[1:])]
data_rs = [y for x in data_connect for y in x]
```

2. 

```py
data = ['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21']
# split data(list) as length 5
data_split = [data[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(data), 5)]
# remove 4th and 5th index value from each list
data_rs = [x for d in data_split for x in d[:3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for according to your post.

1st List

```
data = ['chelsea','manchester','london','liverpool']
new_data = [[data[i*2],f'{data[i*2]}-{data[i*2+1]}',data[i*2+1]] for i in range(int(len(data)/2))]
sum(new_data,[])

['chelsea', 'chelsea-manchester', 'manchester', 'london', 'london-liverpool', 'liverpool']
```

2nd List

```
number = ['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22']
number = [int(i) for i in number]

new_number = [number[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(number),5)]
sum(new_number,[])

[10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22]
```